# How to use wkhtmltopdf.exe in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

After 10 hours and trying 4 other HTML to PDF tools I'm about ready to explode.

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) sounds like an excellent solution...the problem is that I can't execute a process with enough permissions from asp.net so...

```
Process.Start("wkhtmltopdf.exe","http://www.google.com google.pdf");
```

starts but doesn't do anything.

Is there an easy way to either:

-a) allow asp.net to start processes (that can actually do something) or
-b) compile/wrap/whatever wkhtmltopdf.exe into somthing I can use from C# like this: `WkHtmlToPdf.Save("http://www.google.com", "google.pdf");`

Comment: This is not a good idea. IIS7 in integrated mode prohibits this, including impersonation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could also use [Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin)

> .NET Wrapper for WkHtmlToPdf DLL, library that uses Webkit engine to
>   convert HTML pages to PDF.

Nuget packages:

[Pechkin.Synchronized](http://nuget.org/packages/Pechkin.Synchronized/)

[Pechkin](http://nuget.org/packages/Pechkin/)

Comment: Marking this as accepted after all these years because I just had to use wkhtmltopdf again on a new project and Pechkin worked perfectly!

Comment: I am having problem with pechkin or Codaxy or even WkhtmlXSharp, They all do not display Thai fonts (Utf-8) or unicode fonts properly. While using itextsharp and the exe doesn't give that problem

Comment: @DavidMurdoch are you having any file locking errors when deploying new code? if i understand it correctly Pechkin uses a native dll (WkHtmlToPdf) and that native dll might not get unloaded as your managed dlls when you upload new files?

Answer (score 23):

I just started a new project to provide a C# P/Invoke wrapper around wkhtmltopdf.

You can checkout my code at: https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp

Greets.

Comment: wow, that looks pretty slick. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I get errors when I use MultiplexingConverter such "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." Is there a way to prevent this error?

Comment: I don't get my images embedded in the pdf. Nothing shows in where image should display. I checked if it occurred due to relative url of the image and converted it into absolute ones. Still no success. What would work?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Brennan. It works fine the first few tries but then crashes and I have to restart the webserver to get it working again. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: They are working on a workaround ... http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=511&start=100

Comment: I'm also facing the problem - Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. - Has this been fixed? Really need help!

Comment: I really like this solution, but ... nearly 44MB after compiling? Any ideas on decreasing the size?

Comment: @Żubrówka I have the same problem. Has anyone figured out how to fix this issue?

Comment: @crush i ended up just writing a simple wrapper to wkhtmltopdf.exe. It works pretty well and the solution is stable. Depending on your scenario, it might work quite well for you also :)

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net/8812394#8812394), I have found the good [wrapper](https://github.com/codaxy/wkhtmltopdf) written by Codaxy, which can also be easily downloaded via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Codaxy.WkHtmlToPdf).

After a few trials, I have managed this MVC action, that instantly creates and returns the PDF file as a stream:

```
public ActionResult Pdf(string url, string filename)
{
    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument() { Url = url };
    PdfOutput output = new PdfOutput() { OutputStream = memory };

    PdfConvert.ConvertHtmlToPdf(document, output);
    memory.Position = 0;

    return File(memory, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(filename));
}
```

Here, the Pdf* classes have been implemented in the wrapper, with a nice, clean code, unfortunately lacking documentation.

Within the converter, the URL will be converted to a PDF, stored in a temporary file, copied to the stream that we have given as parameter, and afterwards the PDF file is deleted.

Finally, we have to push the stream as FileStreamResult.

Do not forget to set the output stream's Position to zero, otherwise you will see PDF files being downloaded as zero bytes of size.

Comment: To output PDF stream via MVC ActionResult on web browser directly, @endy-tjahjono demonstrated a good approach via [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168846/open-pdf-result-in-browser-tab-with-mvc-3)

Comment: It's working nicely but hanging when I try to use a header (which works normally by using the command line tool directly).

Comment: @marquito: Do you mean "header" tag in HTML5? I do not have any experience, but did you try replacing it with a good old friend "div"?

Comment: @BoltThunder I mean "header" as in using the --header-html modifier. When the path is wrong and it can't retrieve a header, it just hangs (intead of inserting a blank header, for instance)

Comment: The line "return File(memory, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(filename));" is giving me "System.IO.File is a type but it is being used like a variable."

Comment: @HughSeagraves: here File(...) stands for "File" method in the Controller class, not the System.IO.File class.

Comment: how can we make all margins=zero using this library

Answer (score 4):

Here is the actual code I used. Please feel free to edit this to get rid of some of the smells and other terribleness...I know its not that great.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class utilities_getPDF : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = WKHtmlToPdf(myURL);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            string file = Server.MapPath("~\\utilities\\GeneratedPDFs\\" + fileName);
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                var openFile = File.OpenRead(file);
                // copy the stream (thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c)
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                while (true)
                {
                    int read = openFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                openFile.Close();
                openFile.Dispose();

                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }
    }

    public string WKHtmlToPdf(string Url)
    {
        var p = new Process();

        string switches = "";
        switches += "--print-media-type ";
        switches += "--margin-top 10mm --margin-bottom 10mm --margin-right 10mm --margin-left 10mm ";
        switches += "--page-size Letter ";
        // waits for a javascript redirect it there is one
        switches += "--redirect-delay 100";

        // Utils.GenerateGloballyUniuqueFileName takes the extension from
        // basically returns a filename and prepends a GUID to it (and checks for some other stuff too)
        string fileName = Utils.GenerateGloballyUniqueFileName("pdf.pdf");

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                        {
                            FileName = Server.MapPath("~\\utilities\\PDF\\wkhtmltopdf.exe"),
                            Arguments = switches + " " + Url + " \"" +
                                        "../GeneratedPDFs/" + fileName
                                        + "\"",
                            UseShellExecute = false, // needs to be false in order to redirect output
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            RedirectStandardError = true,
                            RedirectStandardInput = true, // redirect all 3, as it should be all 3 or none
                            WorkingDirectory = Server.MapPath("~\\utilities\\PDF")
                        };
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;
        p.Start();

        // doesn't work correctly...
        // read the output here...
        // string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        //  wait n milliseconds for exit (as after exit, it can't read the output)
        p.WaitForExit(60000);

        // read the exit code, close process
        int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
        p.Close();

        // if 0, it worked
        return (returnCode == 0) ? fileName : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't "if 0 or 2, it worked".

It only works when 0. Other values:

1: (or 8?) Generic failure code value of EXIT_ERROR.
2: Error 404, not found (and empty PDF).
3: Error 401, unauthorized.
                  
As per unix specification, any value other than a 0 returned by a process signals some sort of error. This is true for windows programs as well.

Comment: thanks, +1 for the correction. The code (and comments) are originally from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331926/asp-net-calling-exe/1698839#1698839

Comment: I've tried both 0.99 & the newer RC and neither one of them seem to support --redirect-delay - any ideas? What version were you using? It's driving me nuts! It works perfectly aside from not waiting for my ajax calls to laod.

Comment: I'm not too sure if the version I used actually did anything with the redirect-delay switch (I copied the code from someone else).


If wkhtmltopdf is able to run javascript/XHR make sure there are no JS errors. Also, try to make sure the code runs *before* `window.onload`.

Comment: And lastly you could try doing something like this:

(Have a look at: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=315)

` --run-script (function(){var d = new Date()+10000;while(new Date() < d){};}())`

in order to force wkhtmltopdf to wait 10 seconds before capturing the page (as long as it doesn't have a long-running-script timeout).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I post this as an 'answer' to the comments of above answer [How to use wkhtmltopdf.exe in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791981/how-to-use-wkhtmltopdf-exe-in-asp-net/2834549#2834549)

If `--redirect-delay` doesn't work, try `--javascript-delay`
See here for all the options: https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/README_WKHTMLTOPDF

Or do `wkhtmltopdf -H` for extended help (afaik same output as above link).