# Open PDF result in browser tab with MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3. I have a controller action that returns a PDF file like this:

```
Public Class ReportController
    ...
    Function Generate(id As Integer) As ActionResult
        ...
        Return File(output, "application/pdf", "something.pdf")
        ' "output" is a memory stream
    End Function
```

The code works but Firefox doesn't display the result in a tab, the result is either downloaded or opened with Adobe Reader.

I know that *Firefox can display PDF in a tab* because I can just google some PDF, click the link, and the PDF will open in a tab.

How do I set up the action so the PDF will open in a tab?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the answer from the [related links on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724278/asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-get-the-browser-to-open-and-display-a-pdf-instead-of-displ/3724471#3724471):

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline")
Return File(output, "application/pdf")
```

The PDF opens in a tab, but the filename hint is lost, even if I do it like this:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=something.pdf")
Return File(output, "application/pdf", "something.pdf")
```

So finally I didn't bother to give filename hint at all.

EDIT

ASP.NET MVC 3's File with 3 parameters:

```
Return File(output, "application/pdf", "something.pdf")
```

will add `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="something.pdf"` to the response header, even if there is already a Content-Disposition in the response header.

So if you manually added Content-Disposition to the header, and then use File with 3 parameters, you end up with **two** Content-Disposition headers. Firefox 8 will say that the response is corrupted if the response header is like this.

So best way to do it now is add Content-Disposition manually for 'inline', and then use File with 2 parameters:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=something.pdf")
Return File(output, "application/pdf")
```

Comment: Some quick testing showed that Firefox, IE6/IE7, and Chrome all utilize the filename.  However, IE8 did not.  Might be useful to know.

Comment: To get the content type for any type of file (not just PDFs), you can call MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename) in System.Web.

Answer (score 1):

This is configurable in your browser. You can change the settings to download / open in browser or open in relevant application in tools->options->applications section for all file types. Thi has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: But I can find some links to PDF on the internet, and the PDF will open in a tab when I click the link, so I think my browser setting is not the problem.

Comment: try using an iframe and give source as the pdf file path          <iframe src='yourPdfFile.pdf' ></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Try linking directly to the PDF.... If it opens in a tab then try changing your route to end with .pdf