# Generate a pdf from view Mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

Today I received a task to generate a pdf from view .... as I am beginner in programming ... someone would help me with this task .. passing some tips .. where to start researching. Pos'm having difficulty doing this task.
I tried to use an example in this link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3
  but it always throws an error in this part of the code

```
public byte[] Render(string htmlText, string pageTitle)
{
    byte[] renderedBuffer;

    using (var outputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, HorizontalMargin, HorizontalMargin, VerticalMargin, VerticalMargin))
        {
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, outputMemoryStream);
            pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
            pdfWriter.PageEvent = new PrintHeaderFooter { Title = pageTitle };
            pdfDocument.Open();
            using (var htmlViewReader = new StringReader(htmlText))
            {
                using (var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDocument))
                {
                    htmlWorker.Parse(htmlViewReader);// erro here 
                }
            }
        }

        renderedBuffer = new byte[outputMemoryStream.Position];
        outputMemoryStream.Position = 0;
        outputMemoryStream.Read(renderedBuffer, 0, renderedBuffer.Length);
    }

    return renderedBuffer;
}
```

Comment: What does that error message at that line ? Use `Try-Catch` to log your errors.

Comment: What happens is the error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  in line with the comment

Comment: Fabio, please share your View

Comment: take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168846/open-pdf-result-in-browser-tab-with-mvc-3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.Net MVC how to get view to generate PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779430/asp-net-mvc-how-to-get-view-to-generate-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It is not answer to your question per se, but we are mostly using [NReco.PDF](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx)

And example of the code to generate PDF from HTML content would be:

```
var htmlContent = String.Format("<body>Hello world: {0}</body>", 
    DateTime.Now);
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();  
var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(htmlContent);
```

So only thing missing in this example is getting output of you MVC controller as HTML.