# wkhtmltopdf - convert html code to pdf directly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

I know this tool looks up on a url and converts the repsponse to pdf.
How do I convert a

```
<html> content.. </html>
```

into a pdf?

I was looking at the help files on wkhtml2pdf and looks like it provides an option of stdin but I can't really figure out how to emulate stdin.

Also if you know a tool which does a better job, please suggest me some.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331926/asp-net-calling-exe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wkhtmltopdf is a free tool, but it's not written in .NET and it could be kind of hard to integrate into your asp.net application.

you can take a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), which is free, but cannot handle any kind of html, or you can take a look at commercial tools to convert html to pdf, like [ExpertPDF](http://www.html-to-pdf.net) or [ABCpdf](http://websupergoo.com/), that can handle any html/css.

Comment: it's not a problem to integrate it in an asp.net application

Comment: `iTextSharp` has an AGPL copyleft license and cannot be used in commercial applications without making the full source code of the project opened or paying for it

Comment: In my opinion if you want to use WkHtmlToPdf into your C# app. Since the library is built in C++ (https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) and producing a native DLL, I can think about two possible ways for using it from .NET

1. A wrapper library using P/Invoke (DLLimport, ...) for calling native functionality from C#.
2. A wrapper library invoking an executable 

Each one has its advantages and disadvantages, I haven seen nuget packages for both

Answer (score 15):

I just started a new project to provide a C# P/Invoke wrapper around wkhtmltopdf.

You can checkout my code at: https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp

Greets.

Comment: finally someone who works on .NET wrapper. looks promising. I will check it out

Comment: under which license is this distributed ?  can it be used for commercial applications ?

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin)

> .NET Wrapper for WkHtmlToPdf DLL, library that uses Webkit engine to
>   convert HTML pages to PDF.

Nuget packages:

[Pechkin.Synchronized](http://nuget.org/packages/Pechkin.Synchronized/)

[Pechkin](http://nuget.org/packages/Pechkin/)

Example code:

```
private void ConvertToPdf()
{
    var loadPath = Server.MapPath("~/HtmlTemplates");
    var loadFile = Path.Combine(loadPath, "Test.html");
    var savePath = Server.MapPath("~/Pdf");
    var saveFile = Path.Combine(savePath, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss.fff") + ".pdf");

    var globalConfig = new GlobalConfig()
        .SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        .SetPaperSize(PaperKind.A4);

    var pdfWriter = new SynchronizedPechkin(globalConfig);

    pdfWriter.Error += OnError;
    pdfWriter.Warning += OnWarning;

    var objectConfig = new ObjectConfig()
        .SetPrintBackground(true)
        .SetIntelligentShrinking(false);

    var pdfBuffer = pdfWriter.Convert(objectConfig, File.ReadAllText(loadFile));

    File.WriteAllBytes(saveFile, pdfBuffer);
}

private void OnWarning(SimplePechkin converter, string warningtext)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void OnError(SimplePechkin converter, string errortext)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: I just couldn't use this library. Do you have any advice on how **exactly** I should use it? Trying to install it via nuGet gives me a version error (Install-Package : Could not install package 'Pechkin.Synchronized 0.5.8.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project 
that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are 
compatible with that framework.)

Comment: Problem is: I can't even run the dlls inside my web project. Nowhere in the docs I can find what .NET version I should be using. It states not to be compatible with my version, but what version is it compatible with? My PDF generation is working beautifully, full of graphics and coloured tables, but I'm not able to generate it from ASP.NET and this is very frustrating. I feel I'm close but just can't do it.

Comment: @marquito: yeah, it requires .NET 4.0, I checked the dll with JustDecompile and it depends on mscorlib from 4.0

Comment: Hummm... that's bad. Our system is huge and running under 3.5. Thanks for your effort, Mr. @Panda

Comment: @marquito: you might want to just add https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list to your server and call it from C#, it has binaries for windows/linux

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do, to no avail. I feel like a noob. I've tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331926/calling-wkhtmltopdf-to-generate-pdf-from-html/1698839#1698839 It's probably a path issue.

Comment: If you can, please join me at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37112/wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 2):

I found a way.
You can set up another to output the normal html.
And use that url as the input value of wkhtml2pdf process.

----------Edit

```
public byte[] WKHtmlToPdf(string url_input)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileName = " - ";
            var wkhtmlDir = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["wkhtmlDir"];
            var wkhtml = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["wkhtml"];
            var p = new Process();

            string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + @"/application/" + url_input;

            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = wkhtml;
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = wkhtmlDir;

            string switches = "";
            switches += "--print-media-type ";
            switches += "--margin-top 10mm --margin-bottom 10mm --margin-right 10mm --margin-left 10mm ";
            switches += "--page-size Letter ";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = switches + " " + url + " " + fileName;
            p.Start();

            //read output
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            byte[] file;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    if (read <= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                file = ms.ToArray();
            }

            // wait or exit
            p.WaitForExit(60000);

            // read the exit code, close process
            int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
            p.Close();

            return returnCode == 0 ? file : null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           // set your exceptions here
            return null;
        }
    }
```

----------web.config key example

```
  <add key="wkhtmlDir" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin"/>
    <add key="wkhtml" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"/>
```

The basic idea is passing url to the exe as an argument.

HTH !

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to print specific part of html with Css**

install Nuget packages:

Pechkin.Synchronized

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
  pnlprint.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
   string cssPath = Server.MapPath("~/css/style1.css");

    string cssString = File.ReadAllText(cssPath);
     cssPath = Server.MapPath("~/css/bootstrap.css");
    string cssString2 = File.ReadAllText(cssPath);
    cssString += cssString2;
    GlobalConfig gc = new GlobalConfig();
    byte[] pdfContent = new SimplePechkin(new GlobalConfig()).Convert(@"<html><head><style>" + cssString + "</style></head><body>" + sw.ToString() + "</body></html>");
```

here you can easily understand the working of *wkhtmltopdf* https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/366/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-html-using-wkhtmltopdf-with-c-in-winforms