# how do I create pdf fullcalendar for 12 months?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have popular [fullcalendar.js](http://fullcalendar.io/) embedded in my page i can use below code to print for one month

```
<button class="printBtn hidden-print">Print</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.printBtn').on('click', function (){
window.print();
});
```

but now I want to add a print functionality to so that user can print for 12 months.

UPDATE: I want to generate a pdf like how this [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/create.html) creates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can FullCalendar be printed to PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546745/can-fullcalendar-be-printed-to-pdf)