# Is there a way to print a fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, pdf, fullcalendar

Is there a way to print the fullcalendar with content from the website itself?
Because just printing the website messes up the css.

Comment: This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546745/can-fullcalendar-be-printed-to-pdf)

Comment: That was in 2013 and showed it doesn't work. I hoped it would now

Comment: Have you included the print.css supplied by fullCalendar into your page, with the appropriate media attribute?

Comment: Yeah but Its still not lloking right. Its all white, same as on fullcalendars own page. I need the colors to match

Comment: Same as what exactly? Can you please show us a screenshot of what the printout looks like, and then describe exactly what you think is wrong with it. Or provide a drawing of what you want it to look like. And also please show the code of the calendar including how you include the CSS on the page. It's quite hard to be sure about the problem from just a very short statement, and no other details.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CPoykE8, it just looks terrible.