# Pechkin lib throws a TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, wkhtmltopdf, pechkin, tuespechkin

I've tried many examples that use Pechkin and Pechkin.Synchronized but can't get it to run, because all the times, I get the following error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
>   Additional information: Could not load type 'Pechkin.GlobalConfig' from assembly 'Pechkin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I'm using x64 Windows 7 Home Basic with VS2012 Express for Desktop and the csproj is configured to build for x86 target and installed Pechkin and Pechkin.Synchronized from using nuget PM.

The last code I tried was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957268/wkhtmltopdf-convert-html-code-to-pdf-directly-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since you asked this question and you've already fixed your issue, but maybe it'll help someone else.

You should probably try implementing [TuesPechkin](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin) instead. This is a fork of Pechkin solving many issues ([Pechkin issues](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin/issues)) and using the latest version of WKHTMLTOPDF. The developer is quite active and will probably solve any bug you may find.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem was the name of my C# Console project, it was Pechkin. When I changed it to PechkinTest, System.TypeLoadException did not arise.

Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I also got the same problem and i changed my project name from Pechkin to some other name and the problem solved !