# Need Alternative to EO.Pdf for Converting HTML to PDF in C#, wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: c#, html, pdf, c#-4.0, wkhtmltopdf

I am creating a HTML catalog of movies, and then converting it to PDF. I was using EO.Pdf, and it worked for my small test sample.  However, when I run it against the entire list of movies, the resulting HTML file is nearly 8000 lines, and 7MB.  EO.Pdf times out when attempting to convert it.  I believe it is a limitation of the free version, as I can copy the entire HTML and paste it into their online demo and it works.

I am looking for an alternative to use.  I am not good with command line, or running external programs, so I would prefer something I can add to the .NET library and use easily.  I will admit that the use of EO.Pdf was easy, once I added the dll to the libarary and added the namespace, it took one line of code to convert either the HTML Code, or the HTML file into a PDF.  The downsides I ran into were that they had a stamp on every page (in 16pt font) with their website on it.  It also wouldn't pick up half of my images, not sure why.  I used a relative URL in the HTML file to the images, and I created the PDF in the same dir as the HTML file.

I do not want to re-create the layout in a PDF, so I think something like iTextSharp is out.  I've read a bit about something called like wkhtmltopdf or something strange like that.  It sounded good, but needed a wrapper, and I have no clue how to accomplish that, or use it.

I would appreciate suggestions with basic instructions how to use them.  Either a library and a couple lines on how to use it.  Or if you can tell me how to setup/use the wkhtmltopdf I would be extremely greatful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using wkhtmltopdf and I'm very happy with it. One way of using it:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "wkhtmltopdf.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-O landscape <<URL>> -";
p.Start();
```

and then you can get a stream:

```
p.StandardOutput.BaseStream
```

I used this because I needed a stream, of course you can invoke it differently.

---

Here is also a discussion about [invoking wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331926/calling-wkhtmltopdf-to-generate-pdf-from-html)

---

I just saw, that someone is implementing a [c# wrapper for wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp). I haven't tested it, but may be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

After much searching I decided to use HiQPdf.  It was simple to use, fast enough for my needs and the price point was acceptable to me.

```
var converter = new HiQPdf.HtmlToPdf();
converter.Document.PageSize = PdfPageSize.Letter;
converter.Document.PageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
converter.Document.Margins = new PdfMargins(15); // Unit = Points               
converter.ConvertHtmlToFile(htmlText, null, fileName);
```

It even includes a free version if you can keep it to 3 pages.
http://www.hiqpdf.com/free-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx

And no, I am in no way affiliated with them.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ExpertPdf.

[ExpertPdf Html To Pdf Converter](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/) is very easy to use and it supports the latest html5/css3. You can either convert an entire url to pdf:

```
using ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf; 
byte[] pdfBytes = new PdfConverter().GetPdfBytesFromUrl(url);
```

or a html string:

```
using ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf; 
byte[] pdfBytes = new PdfConverter().GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(html, baseUrl);
```

You also have the alternative to directly save the generated pdf document to a Stream of file on the disk.