# Open source/free tools for Website thumbnails creation

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Any open source tools for website thumbnail creation on the fly or for storing on server side??

Most of them provide limited no of thumbnail requests per month in free mode. Are there any services/ tools that're completely open source ?

Comment: I posted something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864629/generate-thumbnails-images-from-a-url/7016244#7016244

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) does the trick:

```
$ wkhtmltoimage http://stackoverflow.com so.png
```

You can convert image formats on a Linux box:

```
$ convert -sample 100x75 so.png small-so.png
```

Or you can script it for all the images:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.png
do
  convert -sample 100x75 "$i" small-"$i"
done
```

Comment: Clarification: The "convert" tool is in the ImageMagick package. It is available on many platforms and is open source.

Comment: This does not make a thumbnail out of a website

Answer (score 1):

use **wkhtmltoimage** part of the [**wkhtmltopdf**](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) project (download the `wkhtmltox` install to get the wkhtmltoimage executable for linux/windows)

it's a command line tool, if you search you'll find lots of hits for `wkhtmltopdf` the syntax is similar `wkhtmltoimage [url] [filename]`

example: `wkhtmltoimage http://stackoverflow.com c:\so.jpg`

someone's implemented the pdf one in ASP.NET: [Calling wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331926/calling-wkhtmltopdf-to-generate-pdf-from-html/1698839#1698839)