# Is it possible to run a plugin system on AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net, plugins, appharbor

I've written a plugin system for my web application where at application start assemblies are read and cataloged.  Is this possible if I have a "plugins" folder that I push to, and how would I reference that folder if it is not located in my webapp folder structure?

**Edit**

I found this this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084552/how-to-run-external-executables-from-an-appharbor-application-html-to-pdf-gener) question regarding the use of exe files for external processes and it seems that files included in the build are a possibility.  Is this a matter of creating a folder in hte application path that IIS can access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ensure that the relevant assemblies are copied to build output, then this should work fine. You can probably accomplish this by including the relevant assemblies in a plugins-directory that's part of the Visual Studio project with the dll's marked as "Content" (as you would for javascript and other content that you want deployed). You can experiment with the AppHarbor build process to get this working by following the suggestions in the [FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/).