# wkhtmltopdf pdf, a way to listen for when the process is complete?

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to generate some pdfs from a asp.net mvc site.  I'm using code found on another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331926/calling-wkhtmltopdf-to-generate-pdf-from-html/1698839#1698839).  There is a problem with this code in that there is a hard coded 60 second wait for the process to complete.  I think it would be much improved if we could simply have a trigger or signal to watch for then exit and read the output.  So does anyone know of a way to listen for a response from the wkhtmltopdf process?

```
 // read the output here...
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 

// ...then wait n milliseconds for exit (as after exit, it can't read the output)
p.WaitForExit(60000); 

// read the exit code, close process
int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
p.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that's doing what you think it is. It will exit as soon as it's complete. the 60 seconds is a maximum wait time for it to complete.

As stated in on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56)

> The WaitForExit(Int32) overload is used to make the current thread
>   wait until the associated process terminates. **This overload instructs
>   the Process component to wait a finite amount of time for the process
>   to exit.** If the associated process does not exit by the end of the
>   interval because the request to terminate is denied, false is returned
>   to the calling procedure. **You can specify a negative number (Infinite)
>   for milliseconds, and Process.WaitForExit(Int32) will behave the same
>   as the WaitForExit overload.** If you pass 0 (zero) to the method, it
>   returns true only if the process has already exited; otherwise, it
>   immediately returns false.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Good point, I just assumed it would always wait the full 60 seconds.