# Convert a html file to PDF (with inline styles)

Tags: c#, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to convert a static html file to pdf file with the styles as it is.
I have only a few fields in html ,
Like text,select,textarea,button,label ( but all contains inline styles)
I have checked itextsharp, which is converting to pdf with no styles.

**Can I generate the pdf as I see the html file in browser**

I am using c# win-form  application to do that.

Comment: Take a look at [wkhtmtopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). Also, possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Comment: i have updated my answer have a look

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# HTML to PDF code for use in a service (on a server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058560/c-sharp-html-to-pdf-code-for-use-in-a-service-on-a-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating pdf from html page using http://www.html-to-pdf.net/  First download dll from site and refer it in ur code...i have written rest of the code below, have a look.

```
 PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
            //pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "put your license key here";

            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.EmbedFonts = false;
            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = false;
            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = false;
            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.GenerateSelectablePdf = true;
            pdfConverter.ActiveXEnabled = true;
            pdfConverter.AvoidImageBreak = true;
            pdfConverter.NavigationTimeout = 2147483647;

            pdfConverter.ScriptsEnabled = true;
            pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.AutoSizePdfPage = true;
            pdfConverter.SavePdfFromUrlToFile(html file path, output file path filepath);
```

Comment: Searched a lot, But couldn't figured  out a exact solution to this problem
" generate the pdf as I see the html file in browser"

Comment: Thanks:), any demo key to test ?

Comment: u dont need a demo key to test ;) it will leave a watermark on the pdf unless u buy a license key

Comment: Marked as answer, thanks

Comment: Is there any other free open source dll for C# doing the same ?

Comment: try this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430590/open-source-html-to-pdf-renderer-with-full-css-support

Answer (score 0):

I use [WKHtmlToPdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) a shell utility which is based on the standard WebKit engine. Give it a try.

Comment: any code samples for C# will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

[Amyuni WebkitPDF](http://www.amyuni.com/en/server/webkitpdf) is a free library that can be used for HTML to PDF conversion. It comes with sample code in C# and C++ and a sample desktop application that you can use for evaluating the results.

*usual disclaimer applies*