# How to send an HTML form in asp.net c# by email?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf, snapshot

In my ASP.Net C# website, I got an order form which I want to be send via email by submitting it. The form elements are HTML and the calculations are done by JavaScript in client-side, and it has lots of form elements.

I want to be able to send the form and its filled contents by user, as PDF or JPG via email.

Maybe the form should be captured as a snapshot from client-side as an image or a print file, then maybe the file can be send from server-side by email.

I'd highly appreciate if you give me a practical described solution. Here is some parts of code as sample:

```
   <div id="cblDomain">
    <input id="cblDomain_1" value="10" onchange="subsumDomain()" type="checkbox" name="cblDomain" checked="checked"><label for="cblDomain_1">com - 10</label><br>
    <input id="cblDomain_2" value="10" onchange="subsumDomain()" type="checkbox" name="cblDomain"><label for="cblDomain_2">net - 10</label><br>
    <input id="cblDomain_3" value="5" onchange="subsumDomain()" type="checkbox" name="cblDomain"><label for="cblDomain_3">info - 5</label><br>
    <input id="cblDomain_4" value="10" onchange="subsumDomain()" type="checkbox" name="cblDomain"><label for="cblDomain_4">me - 10</label>
   </div>

<select name="ddlDomainPeriod" onchange="subsumDomain()" id="ddlDomainPeriod">
    <option value="1">1 yr</option>
    <option value="2">2 yrs</option>
    <option value="3">3 yrs</option>
    <option value="4">4 yrs</option>
    <option value="5">5 yrs</option>
</select>
 <div name="sum" id="sumDomain">10</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function subsumDomain() {
        var _sum = 0;
        var _cblDomain = document.getElementsByName('cblDomain');
        for (i = 0; i < _cblDomain.length; i++) {
            if (_cblDomain[i].checked == true)
                _sum += Number(_cblDomain[i].value);
        }
        var _domainPeriod = Number(document.getElementById('ddlDomainPeriod').options[document.getElementById('ddlDomainPeriod').selectedIndex].value);
        document.getElementById('sumDomain').innerHTML = moneyConvert(_sum * _domainPeriod);

        subTotal();
    }

    function subsumHost() {
        var _hostPrice = Number(document.getElementById('ddlHost').options[document.getElementById('ddlHost').selectedIndex].value);
        var _hostPeriod = Number(document.getElementById('ddlHostPeriod').options[document.getElementById('ddlHostPeriod').selectedIndex].value);
        _hostDiscount = 0;
        if (_hostPeriod > 1)
            _hostDiscount = (_hostPrice * _hostPeriod) * 0.2;
        document.getElementById('sumHost').innerHTML = moneyConvert((_hostPrice * _hostPeriod) - _hostDiscount);

        subTotal();
    }
</script>
```

Any kind help would be highly appreciated (^_^)

Kardo

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a long process. Submit, convert to pdf, save to HDD, attache to email, send email. You can do it but I would consider sending a HTML email. You just store the data (order) in your DB and send the email on a preformed email template. Let the end user print it to pdf or paper etc...

If you really want to do the pdf thing you will need to find a decent library as already suggested.

Well this is how you send the email. I like to create a re-useable email class. You don't have to though if that doesn't suit your needs. But hey, if your gonna create an email, Why not make it an object?

```
using System.Net.Mail;
public class Email
    {

        public MailAddress From { get; set; }
        public MailAddress To { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set;}
        public List<Attachment> attachmentsList = new List<Attachment>();


        public void send()
        {
            //send email
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = Host,
                Port = Port,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(From.Address, Password),
                Timeout = 120000 //2mins
            };

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(From.Address, To.Address);
            message.Subject = Subject;
            message.Body = Body;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            foreach(Attachment attachment in attachmentsList){
                if (attachment != null)
                {
                    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }                
            }

            try
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you need to create your pdf or whatever you choose. Save it to your HDD somewhere. create your email and attach the file(s) as an email attachment (or just send the html body. Use stringReplace() to replace values in an email template. (#price #address #companyname etc).

```
Email newMail = new Email();

newMail.From = new MailAddress("someone@somewhere.com", "Your Name");
newMail.Password = "your outgoing mail password");
newMail.To = new MailAddress("someone@somewhere.com", "Recipient Name");
newMail.Subject = "Your Subject";
newMail.Body = "Your email body";
newMail.Host = smtp.example.com;
newMail.Port = 123;

//add the attachments (example)
 foreach (string fileLocation in AttachmentsList)
 {
 newMail.attachmentsList.Add(new Attachment(fileLocation));
 }

 newMail.send();
```

I Hope that helps in some way...

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It's not exactly what I expected but that's very nice & easy to use solution to email.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to grab your html form and generate a PDF, my favorite tool is [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).  You would have to have this installed on your server though (I'd love to know if others found a .net library for wkhtmltopdf! :]).

Once installed its commandline is very simple:

```
wkhtmltopdf www.myhomepage.com output.pdf
```

Calling it from .net is simple too, example:
[Calling wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331926/calling-wkhtmltopdf-to-generate-pdf-from-html)

There are also .net libraries like [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) that you can use to generate pdfs and other static output types.