# Issues with System.Diagnostics.Process OutputDataReceived and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to generate PDF documents. The solution 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3683756/982119) was working perfectly until it started timing out with larger data sets. Now I am using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608823/982119) to prevent `Process` from timing out. I've pretty much copy/pasted it, and added the following:

```
public byte[] WKHtmlToPdf(string url)
{
    int timeout = 60000;
    int returnCode = 0;
    byte[] file = new byte[932768];

    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        // etc etc, same code as the solution from above

        // ...
        if (process.WaitForExit(timeout) &&
            outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout) &&
            errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout))
        {
            // Process completed. Check process.ExitCode here.
            file = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output.ToString());
            returnCode = process.ExitCode;
        }
        // ...
    }

    return returnCode == 0 ? file : null;
}
```

(The object returned by this method is written to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response`)

The result is better than before in that it doesn't time out, but every page on the PDF file is blank. I've tried explicity telling wkhtmltopdf to use utf-8 but that doesn't work either. The amount of pages is correct though - if I run the tool manually and use the same URL to convert to PDF, I get the same amount of pages.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

If anyone had the same issue as I did, they might want to try the solution [here](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2011/03/rendering-html-as-pdf-using-wkhtmltopdf-in-asp-net/). Worked flawlessly for me.