# How to install wkhtmltopdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do you install wkhtmltopdf in ASP.net MVC 3?  Where do you even begin??  I have tried to read documentation on google, but it hardly makes any sense at all.

Comment: You can start at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331926/calling-wkhtmltopdf-to-generate-pdf-from-html

Comment: "I put the wkhtmltopdf.exe file at the top level directory of the site." -- How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Copy wkhtmltopdf folder containing dlls and exe to your web directory, you can also copy it to bin folder. Then use following code

```
Dim p As Process
     Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()



psi.UseShellExecute = False
psi.FileName = """" + Server.MapPath("~/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe") + """"
psi.CreateNoWindow = True
psi.RedirectStandardInput = True
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
psi.RedirectStandardError = True
psi.Arguments = " """ & <url> & """  """ & <Output path> & """ "
Try
   p.WaitForExit(15000)
Finally
   p.Close()
   p.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: you can add this code in your controller in action like 
  Function WritePDF() As ActionResult
<your code>
 End Function